# Sql Split string and use in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a comma seperated string columns in sql.

For eg

```
declare @grouplist nvarchar(max)
set @grouplist='Country,Region,DEPTNO';
```

I need to split the string by comma and use it in a case sql statement in case conditions.

For eg I need to use splitted string like this

```
 Case 
     When Deptno is not null Then   Cast( DEPTNO as Nvarchar(max)) 
     When Region  is not null Then Region
     When Country is not null then Country
     END
```

Can we split string and use in case sql statement.

I need to generate result like this

[image: table]

i am using a query like this to generate

```
 select  
     Case When Deptno is not null Then  Cast( DEPTNO as Nvarchar(max)) When Region  is not null Then Region When Country is not null then Country  END   ,
     Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, 
     Sum(Sal) Total
     from emp group by  Country,Region,DEPTNO   with rollup having country is not null order by  Country,region,Deptno,  EmpCount desc
```

here the problem is group by clause is passing to the stored procedure as
commaseperated string.

Thanks

Comment: don't quite understand what you want. Can elaborate more with some sample data and expected result ?

Comment: Is your string always going to have the same number of commas?

Comment: it's easy to split a string into a column, but here you are essentially trying to split them into an unspecified amount of columns. Probably not the best way to approach this.